# I can't get the locatedAt geocodeLocation of a coordinate back from the routine

Tags: ios, mapkit, reverse-geocoding

The code is here.
It basically works, but I've lost my way, and can't figure out how to get the "point.title" back from the [geocoder] routine.
The point.title is part of the Mapkit annotation thing. I can as is commented out, put a simple string into the point.title, but what I can't get it to do is return the full 'locatedAT' or indeed any of the placemark.subLocality for eg. items.

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

// Add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
//point.title = @"Where am I?";
//point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";
////////////////////////
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: loc
               completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                   CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                   if (placemark) {

                       // NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
                       //String to hold address
                       NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                      // NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

                     //  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
                     //  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
                     //  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name

                     //  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
                     //  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
                     //  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
                     //  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

                       //Print the location to console
                     //  NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

                      point.title = locatedAt;

                   }
                   else {
                       NSLog(@"Could not locate");
                   }
}
 ];
///////////////////////////

NSLog(@"point.title %@",point.title);

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES]; }
```

Comment: Will you please tell me what error or problem you are getting here?

Comment: What do you want to get from reverse geocoding.

Comment: I am trying to put the locatedAt string into the point.title, or point.subtitle variable. it is generated in the geocoder routine.

Comment: Thanks. The marker is being added ok, the drop pin, but the point.title isn't being added from the geocoder routine. So I have the marker, but not the title from the reversegeocode routine?

Comment: Mahesh - Thanks for the previous answer. It works well. But.. It seems to have been deleted now?

Comment: Yes as you have solved your query by your own that's why i have deleted .

Answer (score 0):

I got my code working by simply adding/modifying the following. I can't see why it works, because the point.title = locatedAt overwrites the final point.title = @"Here I am"; that is outside the braces. Because if I take out those two point.title, and point.sustitle lines, it no longer prints the actual geolocation at the pin.

```
                       //Print the location to console
                      //NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);


                      point.title = locatedAt;

                   }
                   else {
                       NSLog(@"Could not locate");
                   }

    }
 ];
point.title = @"Where am I";
   // NSLog(@"point.title %@",point.title);
point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES]; }
```